# Why is else clause executing in this if, elif, else (instead for one of first two)?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to load json-strings that I saved to textfiles back into Python. Since the json-module gives me an error when I give it an empty file, I did the following:

```
fp = open(filename, 'r')

if fp.readlines() == []
     # return an empty list, since the file is empty
elif fp.readlines() != []
     # return the converted list
```

Since I now have both `if a == b` and `if a != b`, I was very surprised to find that none of the to `if`s get executed, but instead, if I add:

```
else:
     print('something')
```

it actually prints `something`. Why is this happening? How can there logically exist something, its negation and then something else?

Comment: The first `fp.readlines()` reads the whole file, so the next one returns no (further) line to read. You need to rewind the file between them, `close` and `open` it again, or save the results of the first time in a variable and use it from the that point on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `fp.readlines()` *again* if the first comparison fails, and so trying to read the file twice...

You need to (e.g.) save it in a separate variable the first time, and then re-use it the second.

```
fp = open(filename, 'r')
lines = fp.readlines()
if lines == []:
  # return an empty list, since the file is empty
elif lines != []:   ### or just "else:"
  # return the converted list
```

You could also just use `else` with your original version but then (again) you wouldn't have access to the actual lines...

And there may be better ways to determine if a file is empty/doesn't exist (not the same thing).

Comment: But why does it return different things when I call the same function on it? I am not changing the file.

Comment: Once `fp.readlines()` has been run, you can't do it again -- there is a "pointer" which points to the beginning when you open the file, but after running `fp.readlines()` now points to the end, and so a further `fp.readlines()` will not do what you expect.

Comment: When reading json data from a file you should use `fp.read()` also when something returns an error it's a good thing as in python you can catch exceptions look at my answer it should clear it up for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json

file_path = "myfile.json"

def read_json_file(file_path):
    try:
        f = open(file_path, 'r')
        data = json.loads(f.read())
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        return False

data = read_json_file(file_path)

if data:
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
else:
    print("File Empty or Invalid JSON Data")
```

I would recommend trying this approach, remember that try and except is your friend.

If you need to explicitly check that the file is empty you can do this:

```
import os

if os.stat(file_path).st_size > 0:
    #Try reading the file
```

Hope this helps.